# Hide Columns Field to users/ But shows for the admins 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, no-code-solution

I am trying to build a `"Ticket"` custom list for a department, upon when a user request they'll see specific columns. But as for other columns that is only meant for admins uses are to be hidden to other users.

I've tried Modified views and edit site content.  Nothing works so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB way to manage the column level Security. Now you have two options.

1. You would need to build it yourself, [check this example](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/hide-sharepoint-list-columns-based-on-user-permissions.html)
2. Or Use 3rd Party Tool.
   http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx or http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html

Also check this one: http://sharepointpromag.com/blog/3-approaches-restricting-access-sharepoint-columns-and-metadata